# Feathersjs (Client and Server): Authenticate using multiple Social Accounts

Tags: angular, feathersjs

Can someone provide me an example of Authenticating using Feathersjs client (Angular2) and server:

1. Authenticate using Feathersjs client api. For ex.. instagram/facebook
2. Using multiple Social accounts altogether

Just one add-on question after above resolved,
Once token is acquired, Should I make HTTP request directly from client to social api or should I use server side to make requests.

I will appreciate even part-answers as I am struggling to get a start using feathersjs client to do social login.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://github.com/stefanbuck/sails-social-auth-example) yet?

Comment: If the documentation for [client side authentication](http://docs.feathersjs.com/authentication/client.html) and [OAuth2](http://docs.feathersjs.com/authentication/oauth2.html) doesn't answer your question I recommend opening a [new issue](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication/issues/new)

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate using an http post request to the following urls

> /auth/local
>
> /auth/token
>
> /auth/facebook/token
>
> /auth/google/token

You can do local athentication by adding this request to your API service:

```
login(name: string, password:string){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
        let user = {
            "email": name,
            "password": password,
        }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + '/auth/local', JSON.stringify(user),{ headers: headers }).map(
        (response: Response) => response.json()).catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); 
 }
```

> If it was signup instead login the only thing changed would be the url "/users" instead /auth/local.